# Can someone explain how to have some commands in a seperate file locally then the main index.js for Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have seen people being able to have a index.js and then other files where the commands are defined. An example:

Index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!'

//Discord Bot Token
const token = 'token here'
client.login(token);


//Checks if the bot is online
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
```

and then a seperate local document "commands.js"

```
client.on('message', msg => {
 //Makes sure that the bot does not read it's own messages
  if(msg.author.bot) {return;}
  if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'test'){ //Sends the IP
    msg.author.send("test!");
    msg.delete();
}});
```

Hope someone can help me understand how to do it.

Comment: [exports and imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) is what you're after. Useful for organising your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modules to import and export files. Since you are already using `require` (Node's way of doing this because [ES modules are still experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)) to import Discord.js, you can import and export like this:

`module1.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  a: 'Hello, world!',
  b: 3
};
```

`module2.js`

```js
const module1 = require('./module1');
console.log(module1.a); // Hello, world!
console.log(module1.b); // 3

// You can also use destructuring:
const {a, b} = require('./module1');
```

For more information on Node.js modules you can read [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

---

In your situation, I recommend reading [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) on setting up a command handler (where commands are stored in separate files). A basic example:

`index.js`

```js
const {readdirSync} = require('fs');
const {Client, Collection} = require('discord.js');

const prefix = '!';

const client = new Client();
// Create a Collection for the commands
client.commands = new Collection(
  // Get the files in the commands folder
  readdirSync('./commands')
    // Only keep JS files
    .filter(file => file.endsWith('js')
    .map(file => {
      // Import the command
      const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
      // When creating a collection, you can pass in an iterable (e.g. an array)
      // of [key, value]
      // The commands will be keyed by the command name
      return [command.name, command];
    })
);

client.on('message', message => {
  // Exit if it was sent by a bot
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  // Get the arguments and command name
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/);
  const command = args.shift();
  // Exit if there isn't a command
  if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

  // Execute the command
  client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
});

const token = 'token here';
client.login(token);
```

`commands/test.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'test',
  execute(message) {
    // '!test' -> 'test'
    message.channel.send('test');
  }
};
```

`commands/args.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'args',
  execute(message, args) {
    // '!args abc 123' -> 'Arguments: abc, 123'
    message.channel.send(`Arguments: ${args.join(', ')}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: discordjs.guide has a [great article](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/dynamic-commands.html#how-it-works) on that topic too. You should give it a read :)